# Need help at factorial

Tags: factorial

$$\frac{ (2+x)!}{x!}$$
 is there any formula for calculating this?

**I think : x!(x+2)/x! then results in x+2...is this true?**

Comment: $(2+x)! =(2+x) (1+x) x!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $x$ is a positive integer, then

$$ \frac{ (2+x)!}{x!} = \frac{(2+x)(1+x)x!}{x!} = (2+x)(1+x) = 2 + 3x + x^2$$

Notice by definition $n! = n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times ... \times 1 $